# python - passing a list to constructor, incorrect number of arguments error

Tags: python, list, constructor, arguments

I'm passing a list to constructor, but python sees these as separate arguments:

```
def __init__(self, a_parent, a_items):
    super.__init__(self, a_parent)
    self._parent = a_parent
    self._layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self._combo = QComboBox()
    for item in a_items:
        self._combo.addItem(item)
    self._layout.addWidget(self._combo)
    self.setLayout(self._layout)
    self.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
    self.setWindowTitle("Select Review Topic")
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 50)
    self._combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.index_changed)
```

and the call:

```
def select_topic(self):
    topics = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    self.topic_selection_window = SelectTopic(self, self.centralWidget(), topics)
    self.topic_selection_window.show()
```

returns the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

for the life of me I can't see it!

Comment: Which line does that error occur on?

Comment: Go for: `self.topic_selection_window = SelectTopic(self.centralWidget(), topics)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
self.topic_selection_window = SelectTopic(self, self.centralWidget(), topics)
```

That's where that additional argument comes from. You've passed `self` to `SelectTopic.__init__()`. You don't have to, as that method will get the value under `self` passed to it implicitly.

To clarify, these are the values that `__init__()` got from your call:

1. An instance of `SelectTopic`
2. The object you had under the `self` that you've passed to it
3. The return value of `self.centralWidget()`
4. The value under `topics`

That's why it complained about getting 4 arguments instead of 3.

The line we're talking about should look like this:

```
self.topic_selection_window = SelectTopic(self.centralWidget(), topics)
```

If you want to know a little bit more about how `self` works, [this article is a great start](http://www.bitstructures.com/2007/11/python-bound-methods.html).

Comment: also, super should be a function call... super()